# Children Between Them

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

I have some question about the usage of the preposition "*between*" [here](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/i-got-divorced-at-37-and-never-expected-what-came-next_55d2179ce4b07addcb4389da?ncid=txtlnkusaolp00000592&kvcommref=mostpopular):

> At age 37 and with **no children between them**, Brown Hamilton and her husband decided to split.

I cannot find a dictionary definition that fits this usage of "*between*".  Could it be wrong?

Comment: The first three dictionaries I checked had appropriate definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's definition 5 from here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/between).

> a.  By the combined effort or effect of: *Between them they succeeded.*
>
> b.  In the combined ownership of: *They had only a few dollars between
>   them.*

It means that there are no children that they have produced together or that they are both responsible for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is correct. I can't think of a word to directly replace `between`. Looking at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/between, the children (if there were any) would *link* or *connect* the two parties.

Between is a word that can be used to define either what separates two parties, or what brings them together